# Get files from a directory in random order using php (xampp)

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

i'm building a wordpress theme and i'm trying to get the all the jpg files from a directory in random order using php....
im using Xampp on win7 (localhost).

this is the code:

```
<? 
    $dir =  get_template_directory_uri().'/images/top/';

    $file_display = array ('jpg', 'jpeg');
    if(file_exists($dir) == false){
        echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found';
    } else {
       $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
       shuffle($dir_contents);
       foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
           $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
           if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true){ 
                echo '<img  src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" />';    
           }
       }
   } 
?>
```

i always get

```
Directory 'http://localhost/ni/wp-content/themes/A/images/top/' not found
```

i also tried to change

```
$dir =  get_template_directory_uri().'/images/top/';
```

to:

```
    $dir = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Ni\wp-content\themes\A\images\top\";
```

but still no luck, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have and `if` in front in front of the `(file_exists($dir) == false) ` test?

Comment: Yes i edited the question, thank you! i had it on my original code!

Comment: try replacing `get_template_directory_uri` by `get_template_directory`, because the `get_template_directory_uri` gives an URI (and you don't want that)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses As of PHP 5.0 `file_exists` accepts HTTP (amongst a few other protocols) so it shouldn't matter so long as OP is using PHP5.

Comment: using get_template_directory() outputs: C:\xampp\htdocs\Ni/wp-content/themes/A/images/top/ with mixed slashes (linux windows syle?)
and i get 
 Directory '' not found

Comment: but a directory is not a file

Comment: `file_exists` checks whether a file or directory exists - look at the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i made it work.

```
  <? 
            $dir =  get_template_directory().'/images/top';
            $imageDir= get_template_directory_uri().'/images/top';
            $file_display = array ('jpg', 'jpeg');
            if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
              echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found';
            } else {
              $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
              shuffle($dir_contents);
              foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
                $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
                if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
                  echo '<img src="', $imageDir, '/', $file, '"  />';
                }
              }
            } 
  ?>
```

Comment: by using get_template_directory() to get the array. and get_template_directory_uri() to show the images.
thank you all for helping me out to get to this...

Comment: Note that in most cases it's better to use `get_stylesheet_directory()` rather than `get_template_directory()` if you're trying to load assets because if you're using a child theme the former will return the child theme's directory, whereas the latter will return the parent theme's directory, and will thus cause you to miss child-theme assets.